# How can i make my TouchableOpacity's reaction to onPress immediate by changing its opacity so users can easily feel they actually press that button?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Sometimes my app is quite busy with other stuff so for a noticeable amount of time,
it becomes unresponsive to touch events bound to my TouchableOpacity components.

`activeOpacity` property makes the button changing its opacity with some delay (1-2 seconds) if that kind of heavy load being present so users do not feel that they actually press that button and keep pressing until they see a reaction. Of course it creates some frustration for them.

My understanding is that I think these opacity changing animation also requires some communication between JS and native side over the bridge. That's why it is affected by other bridge communication and becomes unresponsive for a while.

Is there any way to overcome this situation in React Native side and make the button immediately change its opacity?
Or can it be handled only by creating a new native button component for that purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `requestAnimationFrame` https://reactnative.dev/docs/timers.

"requestAnimationFrame(fn) is not the same as setTimeout(fn, 0) - the former will fire after all the frame has flushed, whereas the latter will fire as quickly as possible (over 1000x per second on a iPhone 5S)."

Wrap your onPress logic in `requestAnimationFrame` so that the animation happens before the logic.